# CMake best practice using shared libraries versions

Tags: linux, cmake

I'm organizing my "development policies in C" and distributing some codes in static and shared libs.

Static libs are ok, but I found a "gap" about shared libraries in documentation: How to specify the SOVERSION on "find_library".

At this moment I'm building libraries this way:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.11)

set (INSTALL_BIN_DIR "" CACHE PATH "full binary path")
set (INSTALL_LIB_DIR "$ENV{HOME}/embedded/llib/lib" CACHE PATH "full binary path")
set (INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR "$ENV{HOME}/embedded/llib/include" CACHE PATH "full include path")
set (SRC_DIR "src" CACHE PATH "Source files path")
set (H_DIR  "include" CACHE PATH "Source files path")

set (C_FILES )
list (
    APPEND C_FILES
    ${SRC_DIR}/cJSON.c
    )

set (H_FILES )
list (
    APPEND H_FILES
    ${H_DIR}/cJSON.h
    )

# Define Project name
project (cJSON)

# Create a library called "cJSON" which includes the source and header files.
add_library (cJSON SHARED "${C_FILES}")

#set_target_properties(cJSON PROPERTIES
#   PUBLIC_HEADER "include/cJSON.h")

include_directories (include)
# Make sure the compiler can find include files for our Hello library
# when other libraries or executables link to Hello
#target_include_directories (cJSON PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

set_target_properties (cJSON 
                        PROPERTIES 
                            VERSION 1.0 SOVERSION 1
                            PUBLIC_HEADER "${H_FILES}" 
                    )

install(TARGETS cJSON 
# IMPORTANT: Add the foo library to the "export-set"
  EXPORT cJSONTargets
  LIBRARY
  RUNTIME DESTINATION "${INSTALL_BIN_DIR}" COMPONENT bin
  LIBRARY DESTINATION "${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}" COMPONENT shlib
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION "${INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}" COMPONENT dev
  )
```

Running cmake, make and make install it results in:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 takaite takaite    13 Dez  7 11:52 libcJSON.so -> libcJSON.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 takaite takaite    15 Dez  7 11:52 libcJSON.so.1 -> libcJSON.so.1.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 takaite takaite 27194 Dez  7 15:03 libcJSON.so.1.0
```

And in another library, I'm including this way:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.11)

set (INSTALL_BIN_DIR "" CACHE PATH "full binary path")
set (INSTALL_LIB_DIR "$ENV{HOME}/embedded/llib/lib" CACHE PATH "full binary path")
set (INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR "$ENV{HOME}/embedded/llib/include" CACHE PATH "full include path")
set (SRC_DIR "src" CACHE PATH "Source files path")
set (H_DIR  "include" CACHE PATH "Source files path")

set (C_FILES )
list (
    APPEND C_FILES
    ${SRC_DIR}/dict.c
    )

set (H_FILES )
list (
    APPEND H_FILES
    ${H_DIR}/dict.h
    )


# Define Project name
project (dict)

set (CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES_BKP ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES})
# Set lib version to be used
set (CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".so.1")

find_library (
    CJSON_LIB 
    NAMES cJSON 
    PATHS ${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}
    )
set (CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES_BKP})

message ("cJSON_lib: ${CJSON_LIB}")

# Create a library called "cJSON" which includes the source and header files.
add_library (dict SHARED "${C_FILES}" ${CJSON_LIB})

include_directories (${H_DIR} ${INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR})
# Make sure the compiler can find include files for our Hello library
# when other libraries or executables link to Hello
#target_include_directories (cJSON PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

set_target_properties (dict 
                        PROPERTIES 
                            VERSION 1.0 SOVERSION 1
                            PUBLIC_HEADER "${H_FILES}"
                    )

install(TARGETS dict 
# IMPORTANT: Add the foo library to the "export-set"
  EXPORT DictTargets
  LIBRARY
  RUNTIME DESTINATION "${INSTALL_BIN_DIR}" COMPONENT bin
  LIBRARY DESTINATION "${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}" COMPONENT shlib
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION "${INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}" COMPONENT dev
  )
```

I can't believe this is the right way to do it. Could any one show me a better way?

Answer (score 4):

For search specific soversion of library you can use *precise* filename in `NAMES` option for `find_library`:

```
find_library (
    CJSON_LIB 
    NAMES libcJSON.so.1
    PATHS ${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}
    )
```

From the documentation for [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/find_library.html):

> Each library name given to the NAMES option is first considered as a library file name and then considered with platform-specific prefixes (e.g. lib) and suffixes (e.g. .so). Therefore one may specify library file names such as libfoo.a directly. This can be used to locate static libraries on UNIX-like systems.

---

Note, that different **soversion**s of the same library are assumed to be ABI **compatible** with each other. So it is rarely needed to search specific soversion of the library.

Changes in the library, which introduce ABI **incopatibility** should be accompanied with changing library's **version**. E.g: `libcJSON2.so`. So you cannot accidentally find *incompatible* library using `find_library`.