# Make ld ignore directory from /etc/ld.so.conf

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, ld

### TL,DR:

Is there a way for me (no root access) to make the linker (invoked by `gcc`) unaware of the contents of a directory contained in `/etc/ld.so.conf` after it has been cached via `ldconfig`?

### In Detail:

I'm trying (and failing) to compile [HTCondor](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/) on a custom linux distro without root access. For various reasons (see below) I believe that the problems I encounter are related to the fact that there are two versions of libssl and two versions of libcrypto installed on this machine. The newer version (1.0.0) of each of these is located at `/usr/lib64` and an older version (0.9.8) is kept at `/usr/local/lib64` for compatibility reasons. `/etc/ld.so.conf` contains both of these paths, so the linker knows about both.

During compilation I get an error

```
../condor_utils/libcondor_utils_8_7_9.so: undefined reference to `ERR_remove_thread_state'
```

since, for some reason, `libcondor_utils_8_7_9.so` is linked against `libcrypto.so.0.9.8`, while `ERR_remove_thread_state` was introduced in 1.0.0. It appears exactly once in the source code:

```
#if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER < 0x10000000L
    ERR_remove_state( 0 );
#elif OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER < 0x10100000L || defined(LIBRESSL_VERSION_NUMBER)
    ERR_remove_thread_state( 0 );
#endif
```

so the preprocessor seems to make its decision based on version 1.0.0.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469456/keep-gcc-linker-from-using-non-system-libraries-found-in-system-lib64-folder) question made me aware of [this](http://www.kaizou.org/2015/01/linux-libraries/) blog post, so I tried surrogating `cpp` with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/gcc -Wl,-rpath-link="/usr/lib64",-rpath="/usr/lib64" "$@"
```

to no avail, unfortunately.

Just for the heck of it, I also tried commenting the prepocessor directives in the source code snippet above to force the selection of `ERR_remove_state`. This results in the linker warning me that `libssl.so.1.0.0` may conflict with `libssl.so.0.9.8` and, unsurprisingly, produces another "undefined reference" error.

### EDIT:

The problem turned out not to be related to the linker at all. See my answer. However, out of curiosity, I'll leave the question open to see if anyone has a solution for it in its original formulation.

Comment: when linking you can pass the absolute path for the individual libs

Comment: @user463035818 oh man. That's probably a solution. Completely forgot about it. Will try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: *"`libcondor_utils_8_7_9.so` is linked against `libcrypto.so.0.9.8`..."* - Please file a bug report against Condor. OpenSSL 0.9.8 is ancient, and has too many problems to spend time detailing. It should have failed acceptance testing at your organization :o

Comment: I think you should rewind a bit and show how you are compiling and linking your libraries and programs. We need to see the actual arguments to the compiler and linker. LD will happily link against the wrong libraries at runtime. You may get lucky and be able to build your app with RPATHs. That is, linker options `-Wl,-R,/usr/local/lib64 -Wl,--enable-new-dtags`. You need to use them both, and be sure to compile with `-I /usr/local/include` and link with `-L /usr/local/lib64`.

Comment: @user463035818 you had the right idea. See my answer.

Comment: @jww good point. No idea why Condor can still be linked against 0.9.8. And will also ask the admins here why exactly they're still keeping it around. It was never my intention, though, to link against it. The two versions just seem to be getting mixed up by the Condor build system.

Comment: @jww rewinding was a good point. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The comments by @user463035818 and @jww pointed me in the right direction to solve my specific problem, which turned out not be related to the linker directly.

Condor uses cmake as build system, so obviously it makes more sense to try to solve this at the cmake level (n00b here). Somewhere in the depths of all the things cmake does it finds both versions of the libraries and mixes them up for some reason. Invoking `find_library` with a specific version as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34162246/3465171) answer in the main `CMakeLists.txt` solves that problem although it leaves a bad taste of dirty workaround in my mouth.

Making cmake ignore a certain directory when looking for libraries should not be hard, according to the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html). I haven't tried it, though.